# Load partial content with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, mootools

So, now I want to load a page layout and then load the content using AJAX. I am using Mootools `Request.HTML` as it parses the HTML response. The thing here is the javascript content in the page, the inline javascript always executes immediately, however, the external javascript is not executed (evaluated).

For the purpose of testing this, I create an inline script which updates a `<span>` with the current date, then I created an external file with similar contents (this one was to update other `<span>`). This first one (inline) executes as the content is loaded, the second one (external) is not executed.

For the ones who want to know what I am planing to do with this: I will use the new HTML5 `history.pushState` + AJAX to load a page partially, in a way it loads faster to the user and relief the server a little bit (as it will provide less requests).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, there is a not a way that I know of to dynamically load JavaScript text that can be executed. Any Javascript you want to execute has to already be in the page. You can load HTML that references existing functions though. Like `<button onclick='action()' />`. But the `action()` function has to already be in the document. You can also attach events to the HTML elements after they are loaded.

Comment: The thing is: if I have `<script>content...</script>` it works, if I have `<script src="file.js"></script>` in the loaded HTML content, it does not load the file.

Answer (score 0):

[`Request.HTML`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request.HTML) has an option: `evalScripts` and you can choose to evaluate or not evaluate scripts that are included in returned HTML.

So it might be:

```
var myHTMLRequest = new Request.HTML({
    url: '/loadMe.html',
    evalScripts: true
}).get();
```